# django model attribute edit & save with no extra page

Tags: django, forms, templates, object

I rende certain objects values in django template in a form of a table.

I let user to edit the value and save the edit so I can track the history of edit.

At the moment I use django forms to let user do single object attribute value OR chosen objects attribute values OR all of them and save it.

My problem is with forms is that the way it works at the moment is:

user clicks a value in 'main' page so it links to object 'edit' page in which I return a form so user can edit it.

The problem is with that extra url or extra page. I do not want to do it via separate pages.

I would like to click on the object (like in the excel) and change the value there in 'main' page and submit the edits from the same page.

How can I achieve it with django ?

Can somebody point me into right direction and point out what I should read about to understand it or how I should do it ?

I want to edit either single or let user edit multiple objects values and save the changes and still be able to track the history of edits / changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into modals. So when a user clicks to edit it will display a pop-up that you can render the form in without leaving the page.

Comment: I do not want any pop-ups or extra displays...I just want to be able to edit the object withing the field and save the changed value.Should I try to achieve it with some ajax or javascript scripts ?

Comment: Yes if that's what you are wanting you will need to do some JavaScript to show the form on click and then have it processed with an Ajax call. Sorry for the first suggestion as I assumed you only wanted to stay on the same page. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I want to stay on the same page and edit the value as explained like in excel: in the excel you do not have any pop-ups or any other magic tricks: just simple hit the table cell and change the value and boom job done save it. how can I do it with django ? what's best approach to it ?

Comment: The closest you can probably get to excel would be to have the text pre-filled in an editable text area within a form. You would then have a submit button and allow users to change the text field and once hitting submit have Ajax send the data to your view to update the model object

Comment: Cool. Good luck with it.